# How to enable On-Send Feature for New Outlook Web App

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

Does the New OWA support on send?
I have an addin that uses the on-send feature, it works fine in the old OWA but not the new OWA, do i have to do some extra configurations in order to get on-send to work in new OWA?

Answer (score 1):

onSend feature is currently not available on new OWA. We are currently working on it and should be available in the near future (no tentative date available).