# On send feature for Outlook Add-in doesn't trigger

Tags: node.js, api, events, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm trying to build an Outlook add-in which displays a confirmation before sending the appointment invitation. 
I tried to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins and use the sample code provided in https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send with small changes.

**For some reason, seems like the event is not caught.** Can anyone help?

I have asked our office365 admin to create the policy which has set the flag OnSendAddinsEnabled

```
Get-CASMailbox xxx@xx.xx | fl OwaMailboxPolicy
OwaMailboxPolicy : CostEstimationPolicy

Get-OwaMailboxPolicy CostEstimationPolicy | fl onsend*
OnSendAddinsEnabled : True
```

manifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>080cd139-375d-4f68-bdc6-f5ab58b9b7c6</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Kevin Ren</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Cost Estimation Warning" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Cost Estimation Warning"/>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this particular case the function calculateCostAndWarn will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="calculateCostAndWarn" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
          <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
          <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" ></bt:Url>
        </bt:Urls>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

index.html

```html
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. -->
<!-- See LICENSE in the project root for license information -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>No UI</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    This page is left blank intentionally.
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
var mailboxItem;


Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

// Entry point for add-in before send is allowed.
function calculateCostAndWarn(event) {
 shouldChangeSubjectOnSend(event);
}

// Check if the subject should be changed. If it is already changed allow send. Otherwise change it.
// <param name="event">MessageSend event passed from the calling function.</param>
function shouldChangeSubjectOnSend(event) {
    mailboxItem.subject.getAsync(
        { asyncContext: event },
        function (asyncResult) {
            addCCOnSend(asyncResult.asyncContext);
            //console.log(asyncResult.value);
            // Match string.
            var checkSubject = (new RegExp(/\[Checked\]/)).test(asyncResult.value)
            // Add [Checked]: to subject line.
            subject = '[Checked]: ' + asyncResult.value;

            // Check if a string is blank, null or undefined.
            // If yes, block send and display information bar to notify sender to add a subject.
            if (asyncResult.value === null || (/^\s*$/).test(asyncResult.value)) {
                mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Please enter a subject for this email.' });
                asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
            }
            else {
                // If can't find a [Checked]: string match in subject, call subjectOnSendChange function.
                if (!checkSubject) {
                    subjectOnSendChange(subject, asyncResult.asyncContext);
                    //console.log(checkSubject);
                }
                else {
                    // Allow send.
                    asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
                }
            }

        }
      )
}

// Add a CC to the email.  In this example, CC contoso@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
// <param name="event">MessageSend event passed from calling function</param>
function addCCOnSend(event) {
    mailboxItem.cc.setAsync(['a@b.com'], { asyncContext: event });        
}

// Check if the subject should be changed. If it is already changed allow send, otherwise change it.
// <param name="subject">Subject to set.</param>
// <param name="event">MessageSend event passed from the calling function.</param>
function subjectOnSendChange(subject, event) {
    mailboxItem.subject.setAsync(
        subject,
        { asyncContext: event },
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Unable to set the subject.' });

                // Block send.
                asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
            }
            else {
                // Allow send.
                asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: On Send add-ins are not supported yet in New Outlook Web App. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510506/how-to-enable-on-send-feature-for-new-outlook-web-app)

Comment: thanks guys, you are right.. switching back to the old owa works.

Comment: now strangely, it blocks my send all the time. even i have empty function

function calculateCostAndWarn(event) {
}

or 

function calculateCostAndWarn(event) {
 event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}

Comment: Can you raise the new issue as a separate question? It will get more attention than asking it here, in the comments.